# How come my adb can't simulate a touchscreen tap?

Tags: adb, touchscreen

[I've read](https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-adb-text-input-shortcut/) I can simulate a tap on my touchscreen by using adb but it doesn't work:

```
C:\>adb shell input touchscreen tap 1 1
Error: Unknown command: touchscreen
usage: input [text|keyevent]
       input text <string>
       input keyevent <event_code>
```

How come I can't send a tap to my device? I have the latest version of the SDK tools and the SDK platform tools. `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32`. Thanks

Comment: Open a terminal on your device and type `input`. What options does it show? Is your Android version beyond 4.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of SDK tools has nothing to do with the parameters `input` can understand or execute. Input is a binary in Android OS which can be run independently without requiring any set of external tools such as ADB.

The reason you receive the error "`Error: Unknown command: touchscreen`" is because you're running an Android version earlier than Android 4.1.1. You would already notice that in the `input` usage you posted, the binary entertains only two parameters i.e. `text` and  `keyevent`.

In Android 4.0.x, the `input` command's usage remains the same as the one you posted. In fact, even Android 2.3.7 has the same input command's usage. (See [com.android.commands.input.Input on GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/search/?r=repository.grepcode.com$java$ext&start=0&query=input.java&entity=type) for comparison of command's usage between Android versions.)

It was Android 4.1.1 which introduced `tap` and `swipe` parameter with usage,

```
usage: input ...
       input text <string>
       input keyevent <key code number or name>
       input tap <x> <y>
       input swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>
```

See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/com/android/commands/input/Input.java#Input) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of android don't have the `tap` feature of the `input` command. I have a 4.0 device which lacks it as well.